# Incorrect sudo password after manually changing the password

Tags: ansible

Consider this simplified ansible task where I create a user with a salted password:

```yaml
// vars
name: "foo"
password: "pwd"
salt: "salt"

// task
- name: Setup users
  user:
    name: "{{ name }}"
    password: '{{ password | string | password_hash("sha512", (salt | string | default(""))[:16] | regex_replace("[^\.\/a-zA-Z0-9]", "x")) }}'
    state: present
    shell: /bin/bash
    update_password: always
```

Everything worked perfectly until the server prompted me to change the password after many months, I was in a rush so I manually changed it... Now I'm trying to make the change on my playbook but no luck, I get `Incorrect sudo password` when gathering facts. I double checked the password and I can confirm that I'm using the same one on the server, I can normally `sudo` on the server. What should I do to match the password on the server?

**edit:**

below is the content of auth.log when the error occurs:

```
Sep 18 21:18:30 myhost sshd[2256]: Connection from myIP port 33766 on serverIP port 22
Sep 18 21:18:31 myhost sshd[2256]: Postponed publickey for foo from myIP port 33766 ssh2 [preauth]
Sep 18 21:18:31 myhost sshd[2256]: Accepted publickey for foo from myIP port 33766 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:FfrBJTV5NjTZwI0rMRPotXIz0KVUJxYtXBH4bQnQlXY
Sep 18 21:18:31 myhost sshd[2256]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user foo by (uid=0)
Sep 18 21:18:31 myhost systemd-logind[1272]: New session 21148 of user foo.
Sep 18 21:18:31 myhost sshd[2256]: User child is on pid 2335
Sep 18 21:18:32 myhost sshd[2335]: Starting session: command for foo from myIP port 33766 id 0
Sep 18 21:18:32 myhost sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1001 euid=0 tty= ruser=foo rhost=  user=foo
Sep 18 21:18:34 myhost sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Sep 18 21:18:34 myhost sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [foo]
Sep 18 21:18:34 myhost sudo: foo : 1 incorrect password attempt ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/foo ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-qaksizygaygpclmzkiyxtajmhinpwxlq ; /usr/bin/python3
Sep 18 21:18:34 myhost sshd[2335]: Close session: user foo from myIP port 33766 id 0
```

Comment: Your ansible become user should use an ssh key and passwordless sudo. It should also be a separate user account, not your regular user.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm already using an ssh key but I `set_fact` `ansible_become_password` to the password. The playbook worked perfectly for several months... I may use passwordless sudo user in the future. But my question is why when I manually changed the password on the server, ansible no longer can `sudo`?

Comment: Are you using the right password? Did you check the server's logs?

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure it's the same, I've just run `ansible -b -K -u foo -i inventories/production all -m ping` with the same password and user, but I keep getting "Incorrect sudo password", I've added the server's logs to the question just in case.

Comment: Well, the server seems to think you used the wrong password. I would suggest you reset it (again) and be 100% sure of it.

Comment: I've changed it to a simple password and it's now working with ansible, thanks! I've reset it again to the old one and it doesn't work, the password contains some special characters like " ' and @, and I'm 100% using the same password, I even copy paste just in case. The very first old password had also special characters but it was working flawlessly, maybe because it was set with ansible and there's some escaping. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hm, yes, if there are special characters then something probably did get escaped somewhere. I couldn't tell you where that is, though; my ansible user uses _only_ ssh keys with passwordless sudo :)

Comment: Well thank you, you may add an answer and I will accept it.